# use cdh3u3 hadoop with dumbo to do mapreduce generate error

Tags: hadoop-streaming

my python script:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import sys
    import dumbo
    import cgi, urlparse
    #from dumbo.lib import JoinReducer
    #from dumbo.decor import primary, secondary

```
def mapper(key, value):
    line = value.split('\t')
    line[1] = float(line[1])  # Unix timestamp
    line[3] = int(line[3])    # Port
    line[4] = float(line[4])  # Delay
    url_part = urlparse.urlsplit(line[6])
    if url_part.path not in ('/android-test.htm',
                    '/iphone-test.htm',
                    '/symbian-test.htm',
                    '/meego-test.htm',
                    '/mobile-test.htm',
                    '/showlog.php',
                    '/showlognew.php',):
        qs_dict = cgi.parse_qs(url_part.query)
        line[6] = qs_dict
        line[7] = int(line[7])    # HTTP status code
        yield line
def reducer(key, values):
    yield key, values

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dumbo.run(mapper)
```

exec command:

```
dumbo start logparser.py -input analytics.log-20111209 -output analytics-log -python \ python2.6 -hadoop /usr/local/cloudera/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u3/
```

hadoop error in jobtracker log

```
    2012-03-15 09:53:18,931 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from attempt_201203131446_0006_m_000003_2: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:391)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TypedBytesOutputReader.readKeyValue(TypedBytesOutputReader.java:57)
        at org
thanks in advance all help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to yield both key and value separately on the map stage.

```
def mapper(key, value):
    ...
    yield line[0], line[1:]
```

Also be sure that your mapped value is a single object so you have to wrap multiple values into tupple or a list.